# Java .class File (Simple)

Tags: java, class, file

I am sort of new to java. How can I use a compiled .class file for programming? Or, how can I use a .net dll meant for java to program? What I am really trying to do is figure out how to use the .net java output from this project here: https://github.com/shtejv/ARDrone-Control-.NET

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files in ARDrone_Java directory seem to be a JNI-wrapper for DLLs. Just add *.java to your source or put *.class in your CLASSPATH and use.

Comment: However that .java file looks like  a header. Is there anything else I need to add? The DLLs for example?